# Number of bars in histogram - R

Tags: r, histogram, axis-labels, bins

I have two problems with the histogram I'm making: I'm trying to generate an histogram in R, using the function `hist()`, for a frequency distribution of a numeric (interval) variable, which ranges from 0 to 10. The plot I'm aiming for should generate 11 bars. However:

Problem 1: My good friend R keeps plotting 10 bars. 
Problem 2: Besides, I have no idea how to plot the "x" tick values in the proper way: below each bar, the category value in "x" (i.e., from 0 to 10). I have tried using `axis()`, as you can see below in my code, but I have no idea how to set this.

I'm pretty sure it is something quite basic, but I cannot find the solution to these two problems. To solve the first one, I thought setting `breaks=11` would solve it, but it didn't work. I have no idea how to solve the second one.

This is my data (128 participants in a study, each scored a value between 0 and 10):

```
structure(list(ID_Esc_Def = c(915151L, 91494L, 1303553L, 1310117L, 
1305411L, 1312263L, 1310121L, 1312264L, 1306498L, 1305413L, 1306497L, 
1307521L, 1305409L, 1307523L, 1306491L, 1311366L, 1307532L, 915155L, 
917111L, 915152L, 917120L, 1312267L, 1310119L, 1310114L, 1305414L, 
1305412L, 1306494L, 1303559L, 1307526L, 917112L, 91496L, 1305410L, 
1307527L, 917113L, 1307529L, 91491L, 1306495L, 1311363L, 1306493L, 
1312260L, 1306496L, 91493L, 1303561L, 915153L, 1310118L, 1307530L, 
1303557L, 1310113L, 1303556L, 1312259L, 1312258L, 91498L, 1311361L, 
1311367L, 1311365L, 1306499L, 1312262L, 915149L, 915148L, 91492L, 
1310120L, 1308168L, 1312266L, 1308167L, 1306492L, 1307531L, 1305408L, 
1307514L, 1310116L, 1310112L, 1306490L, 1307525L, 1310115L, 1308174L, 
1311368L, 915157L, 1312261L, 1308169L, 1312265L, 91495L, 1311360L, 
1305417L, 91489L, 915154L, 1303555L, 91497L, 917118L, 131389L, 
521390L, 521389L, 915150L, 131386L, 1305415L, 1311362L, 521386L, 
131382L, 91490L, 521391L, 1305416L, 1303562L, 1311369L, 917116L, 
521388L, 917114L, 1303558L, 521396L, 521387L, 1308172L, 131388L, 
521395L, 131390L, 131384L, 917117L, 1311364L, 131387L, 1308173L, 
917119L, 131385L, 917115L, 915156L, 521393L, 1308171L, 1308170L, 
1303560L, 521392L, 131391L, 131383L, 1303554L), asig_dic = c(0L, 
10L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 5L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 3L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 10L, 4L, 
6L, 1L, 9L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 
6L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -128L))
```

This is the code I'm using to generate the histogram:

```
m<-mean(dictator$asig_dic)
std<-sqrt(var(dictator$asig_dic))

quartz()
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
par(las=1)

hist(dictator$asig_dic, breaks = 11, col = "grey", freq = F, ylim=c(0,0.4), xaxt="n",
     xlab="Generosity (Donated Tokens in DG)", ylab="Relative Frequency", main="")

curve(dnorm(x, mean=m, sd=std), 
      col="darkblue", lwd=2, add=TRUE, yaxt="n")

axis(1, at = seq(0, 10, by = 1), las=1)
```

As you can see, there are 10 bars. Any help?

All the best,

Mauricio.

Comment: `hist` gives your value of `breaks` to `pretty`, which only takes it as a suggestion. It uses 10 instead of 11, because that's a nice round number and that's how `pretty` rolls.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to drink the `ggplot2` Kool Aid. As you can see, there are 11 bins (as requested) and the labels are at the centre of the bars.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

ggplot(dictator) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x = asig_dic, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
                 bins = 11, fill = "gray", colour = "black") +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, 
                args = list(mean = mean(dictator$asig_dic), 
                            sd = sd(dictator$asig_dic)),
                colour = "salmon", size = 1.25) +
  theme_tufte() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 1),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20)) +
  xlab("Generosity (Donated Tokens in DG)") +
  ylab("Relative Frequency") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:10)
```

[image]

Comment: You can simply use `y = ..density..` instead of `y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))`

Comment: @Lyngbakr: This is just what I was looking for!! It seems I really need to get into `ggplot2`. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

As @Lyngbakr said, you don't get 11 bins because the `breaks` argument in `hist()` uses `pretty` values. The problem with `pretty` values is they are chosen so they are 1,2, or 5 times a power of 10. Therefore, you get only 10 bins and not 11. One way to "fight" it is to use more bins than necessary (e.g `breaks = seq(-1, 10, 1)` or `breaks = seq(0, 10, 0.5)`). However, it might "ruin" your graph. 
You can look [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pretty.html) for help on `pretty` values, and [here](https://planspace.org/20141225-how_does_r_calculate_histogram_break_points/) for a more in-depth explanation.

If you would still like to use `base R` (and not other packages like `ggplot2`), you can do this:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
par(las=1)
hist(dictator$asig_dic,
     breaks = seq(-1, 10, 1),
     col = "grey", freq = F, ylim=c(0,0.4), xaxt="n",
     xlab="Generosity (Donated Tokens in DG)", ylab="Relative Frequency", main="")
curve(dnorm(x, mean=m, sd=std), 
      col="darkblue", lwd=2, add=TRUE, yaxt="n")
axis(1, at = seq(-1, 11, by = 1), las=1)
```